# Is there a POSIX shell alternative to read -e?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, readline

How can I achieve the effects of `read -e` (which turns on line editing via `readline` and is available in `bash`) from a general (POSIX) shell? I don’t want to lose POSIX compatibility just because of this one command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`readline` is a GNU project (developed alongside `bash`). There are other alternatives like BSD libedit, and all POSIX shells have their own line editor, either specific to the shell or based on either of those libraries that implement at least a `vi` editing mode (the only one specified by POSIX, though most also support an `emacs` mode (not specified by POSIX because RMS objected to it)).

POSIX however only specifies that line editing mode for the shell command line, not for `read`.

`ksh93` does support it with `read` though (provided stdin and stderr are on a terminal device). There, you can do:

```
set -o emacs
IFS= read -r 'line?prompt: '
```

The `zsh` equivalent is with the `vared` (variable editor) builtin:

```
line=; vared -p 'prompt: ' line
```

That's the most feature rich with its history handling and the complete customisation of key binding and completion.

`read -e` is `bash` specific.

```
IFS= read -rep 'prompt: ' variable
```

There is no POSIX equivalent. POSIXly, you could start `vi` (specified by POSIX) to edit a temporary file and read the content of that file into a variable.

Alternatively, you could look for the availability of one of `zsh`/`bash`/`ksh93` or `rlwrap` or other wrappers around libreadline, or `socat` (provided it has been built with `readline` support) and use any of those if available to read the line or revert to plain `read` or `vi` if not.

Or use that [`LE` line-editor function seen in this similar Q&A](/a/113450) that implements a limited `emacs`-like line editor.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX `read` only supports `-r` (to be able to read backslashes).  There is no way to ask the user for input and provide command line-like editing, unless you fire up an editor for a file that you later parse.